# String permutation with recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am a java beginner and trying to do a string permutation practice from java programming book. I am defining two method:

```
public static void displayPermutation(String s)
public static void displayPermutation(String s1, String s2)
```

The first method simply invokes `displayPermutation(" ", s)`. The second method uses a loop to move a character from s2 to s1 and recursively invokes it with a new s1 and s2. The base case is that s2 is empty and prints s1 to the console.

Can anyone help me to find what is the problem of the following code?

Her's example:

```
 public static void displayPermutation(String s) {
            displayPermuatation("", s);
        }

    private static void displayPermuatation(String s1, String s2) {
        //base case: when s2 is empty, print s1
        if (s2.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
        else {          
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
                        //move a char from s1 to s2, and recursively invokes it with 
                        //new s1 and s2
            s1 = s1 + s2.charAt(i);
            s2 = s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i+1);
            displayPermuatation(s1, s2);
        }
    }
   }
```

if s = "abc",
it prints only:
abc
acb

it seems that in the first call of displayPermuatation("", "abc"), it does not finish the for loop....
any comments?

Thanks for all the comments below. I think the mistakes I made is because that passing object as argument to a method is actually passing the reference. it is not like primitive data (passing by value). When changing the object, it will affect following method call using that object.

Comment: what should be the correct result when s="abc"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it to the post. The expected results are: abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger, or dropping printouts into your displayPermutation routine to see what it's actually doing (as opposed to what you assume it's doing)? I think you can figure this out yourself with that bit of info.

Comment: You're checking `s2.length()` while assigning a new value to `s2` inside the loop. This might be problem.

Comment: @keshlam yes, I did try debugger, and find out it does not finish the for loop in the call of displayPermuatation("", "abc").

Answer (score 5):

Do not alter `s1` and `s2` in the loop, that causes the error. Simply pass those definitions as arguments to recursive function. Like this:

```
.
.
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        displayPermuatation(s1 + s2.charAt(i), s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i+1));
    }
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your code is that you are changing value of s1 and s2 in the loop which affects the following iterations in the loop, see the following code where I have fixed this issue.

```
public static void displayPermutation(String s) {
    displayPermuatation("", s);
}

private static void displayPermuatation(String s1, String s2) {
    // base case: when s2 is empty, print s1
    if (s2.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            // move a char from s1 to s2, and recursively invokes it with
            // new s1 and s2
            displayPermuatation(s1 + s2.charAt(i), s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works! I am going to edit my post, adding some comments for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the original values for `s1`, `s2` in the loop:

```
private static void displayPermuatation(String s1, String s2) {
    //base case: when s2 is empty, print s1
    if (s2.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
    else {       
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
                    //move a char from s1 to s2, and recursively invokes it with 
                    //new s1 and s2
        string new_s1 = s1 + s2.charAt(i);
        string new_s2 = s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i+1);
        displayPermuatation(new_s1 , new_s2 );
    }
}
```