# String permutation from Java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, permutation

I am new to Javascript and I was trying to reproduce a Java string permutation using Javascript but I cannot get the correct result.

Note: I followed this algorithm here (Hemant's answer): [String permutation with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262915/string-permutation-with-recursion)

Here is my code:

```
function getAllPermutations(input){
  var permutations = [];

  function loop(prefix, input){

      var len = input.length;

      if(len==0) {
          permutations.push(prefix);
       }
      else{
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        loop(prefix + input.charAt(i),input.substr(0,i) + input.substr(i+1,len));
       }
      }
     }

  loop("", input);

  return permutations;
}
```

When I call `getAllPermutations("good")`, it's only returning `["good"]`. What's going on with this code? Am I missing anything about the call back scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `i` in the `for` loop is defined globally. Therefore in each recursion the variable retains the value of the former iteration.
It can be fixed by writing `var` in front of the variable to make it a local variable like in the following code snippet.

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
// ...
}
```